# Expression with Arithmetic Derivative (Math Olympiad)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic

For all primes, the arithmetic derivative is $1$.

Product Rule: $(xy)^\prime=x^\prime y+xy^\prime$ and $0^\prime=1^\prime=0$.

Now, there is also some lesser-known sub-part to the arithmetic derivative called the Arithmetic Product Derivative, $P(n)$. In this case, if 
$$
n=p_1^{x_1} \cdot p_2^{x_2} \cdot \dotsc \cdot p_k^{x_k}, \text{ the prime decomposition of } n 
$$
then
$$
P()=x_1 \cdot p_1^{x_1−1} \cdot x_2 \cdot p_2^{x_2−1} \cdot \dotsc 
 \cdot x_k \cdot p_k^{x_k−1}
$$

> Are there are infinitely values of $n$ such that $(n)=(n−1)+1$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the abc conjecture?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Or maybe a special case that's already a theorem?

Comment: @Vasco You don't need to find italicised letters somewhere to copy-paste into MathJax; the dollar environments will italicise everything automatically.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don't think so. Maybe a special case that's already a theorem.